# Error:Could not run build action using Gradle installation 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\gradle\gradle-2.2.1'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Ive just installed android studio 1.0 RC2 in a windows 8.1 64bits, but when i try to create a new project it says Error:Could not run build action using Gradle installation 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\gradle\gradle-2.2.1'., please help me solve this proplem, im really stuck in this

Comment: There seems not enough information to help the OP

Comment: See what build actions are configured in gradle

Comment: Problem solved, i had to unistall android studio and delete .gradle folder and everything related with android studio and now it works!!

Comment: For android studio 3.0.1 using gradle-4.1-all.zip `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip`  change it to 
`distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip` just remove the backSlash after http. Solved Mine

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Try this:

1) File -> Invalidate caches / Restart

2) Shutdown Android Studio

3) Remove .gradle folder in the user home directory

4) Restart Android Studio let it download all the Gradle stuff it needs

5) Gradle build success !

6) Rebuild project.... success !

Comment: thanks, this solved the problem for me. it is kind of annoying that android studio does not work out of the box.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. @user3430710, could you accept or say why it was not accepted?

Comment: Thanks, removed the ~/.gradle folder solved the issue for me.

Comment: can you explain a bit more why this happens? in my .gradle I had sever versions (2.2.1-all, 2.4-all, 2.4-bin, 2.8-all). Thanks

Comment: I was working on OSX and your answer helped. Quick reminder, make sure you are properly connected to the internet :)

Comment: This worked like a charm. I tried so many different things. This also works only when done in exact order as mentioned. Thanks @Griffin

Answer (score 5):

We have two famous way for this problem:

**1- update the gradle:**

*step 1:*

Get latest version supported by Android Studio from:

[https://services.gradle.org/distributions](http://gradle.org/gradle-download/)

*step 2:*

Extract the gradle file and install to dists folder(gradle folder): default location is: C:\Users[username]\gradle\wrapper\dists

*step 3:*

Open Android Studio: File/Settings/Gradle/Service directory path: (Change to folder you set above) and Click ok.

Status on bottom should indicate it's busy & error should be fixed.

*step 4:*

restart Android Studio

**2- Delete the .gradle folder:**

default location is:

C:\Users[username]\gradle\wrapper\dists

after that open Android Studio and make a new project (might need to reastart).