# Could not run phased build action using Gradle installation '...\gradle-5.4.1'

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I am trying to set up a Java project  in Eclipse which uses Gradle for its builds plus some self-defined Groovy code for the builds (placed - as usual - under buildSrc). 
So I first created a Java project from the existing code and then additionally assigned the "Gradle nature" to the project. Since then I keep getting this error message:

```
Could not run phased build action using Gradle installation 'C:\opt\gradle-5.4.1'. 
Execution failed for task ':buildSrc:compileGroovy'. 
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

What is this message trying to tell me???

Comment: This seems to be weird bug. I copied the entire project to another. Now the original project doesn't show the error anymore, but the copied one still does. ||-(

Comment: Please check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74094370/6533159

Comment: Please check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74094370/6533159

Comment: Please check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74094370/6533159

Answer (score -1):

This issue was raised several times in the past. To solve it:

1. Delete all the files in the .gradle directory in your project and under your username, e.g.:

   ```
   C:\Users\username\.gradle
   ```
2. Restart your computer.
3. Run Eclipse as administrator.
4. Build the project.
5. Finally, if you have any script which runs Gradle in addition to the installation /distribution of Gradle that Eclipse knows - do NOT use the script. It seems to confuse Eclipse regarding the location of Gradle.

Comment: Why the need to delete `~/.gradle`? Also, why the need to restart the machine! This answer isn't useful at all.

Comment: joker, at least for me, it indeed worked only after I deleted .gradle. However, there were some files for which exiting Eclipse wasn't enough - they had some lock, and I could delete them only by rebooting.

Comment: BTW, the suggestion to delete .gradle appears also in similar threads, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32887623/errorcould-not-run-build-action-using-gradle-installation-gradle-2-4-android   and    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951027/errorcould-not-run-build-action-using-gradle-installation-c-program-files-and