# "Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution"

Tags: eclipse, gradle, buildship

I'm having various Gradle problems after a new clean Eclipse install.
They seem to be associated w/ this "Problem" message:

```
Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1.1-bin.zip'.
Initialization script 'Z:\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.buildship.core\init.d\eclipsePlugin.gradle'
Could not compile initialization script 'Z:\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.buildship.core\init.d\eclipsePlugin.gradle'.
startup failed:
General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 60
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 60
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:196)
.....
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
1 error
```

I've already tried deleting .gradle & "Gradle->Refresh Gradle Project".
I've also tried this:
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32887623/errorcould-not-run-build-action-using-gradle-installation-gradle-2-4-android)

My Java install is clean:

```
java version "16.0.1" 2021-04-20
```

& confirmed Eclipse is pointing to it ("Preferences->Java->Installed JREs").

Installation details:

```
Buildship: Eclipse Plug-ins for Gradle  3.1.5.v20210113-0929
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 4.20.0.20210612-1200
```

Windows 10.

Eclipse Install Err Log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.buildship.core 2 2 2021-07-09 11:22:05.951
!MESSAGE Initialize project testgradleprj failed due to an error in the referenced Gradle build.
!STACK 0
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1.1-bin.zip'.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gradle 6.8 does not work with Java 16.
Java 16 supported starting with Gradle 7

"In previous Gradle versions, running Gradle itself on Java 16 resulted in an error."

https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/release-notes.html#java-16

Comment: I changed the Gradle version to 7.1.1 in the Preferences->Gradle.  Same problem.

Comment: "...tried deleting .gradle". Both the project and use home  ones?

Comment: Yes. everything scrubbed.

Comment: OK, it's working now. I created another test gradle project.  build.gradle file now included and "Add Gradle Nature" now working.

Comment: Nice, you can accept the answer if you agree :-)

Comment: @JDOaktown if your gradle is in offline mode and you try to add a dependency then you'll get this useless ass error message which does a terrible job describing the actual error.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to LMC. I changed the project prefs->Gradle from Wrapper to Specific=7.1.1 :

[image]

Comment: You could also try [upgrading the wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html).

Comment: Thanks. I saw this but couldn't figure out how to apply it against Eclipse. I right-clicked the "wrapper" task in the Gradle Tasks button but still not clear.

Comment: OK. I did the following:

Z:\eclipse-workspace\gradleprj4>.\gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 7.1.1


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 up-to-date

Comment: Eclipse will respect the wrapper in the project I think.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my gradle-warpper.properties file with

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.4.1-bin.zip
from
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-bin.zip

and refresh the gradlew project in eclipse. It's build successfull
Note : Java 11 version is installed in my machine

Answer (score 0):

Change your `gradle.properties` file

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip
```

And `build.gradle` file

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because Eclipse was running upon a JVM that was different from the one used by my local Gradle.

I edited the *eclipse.ini* file so that Eclipse would run on the same JVM as my local Gradle (i.e. the one pointed by `JAVA_HOME`) and it worked!