# Buildship: Unsupported class file major version 60

Tags: eclipse, gradle, buildship

After upgrading to Eclipse/Spring Tool Suite 4.11.0, Gradle refresh on a Java 15 project fails to work and reports the error `Unsupported class file major version 60` (= Java 16), even though Java 15 is set up in Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs.

Gradle Buildship is installed as Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to explicitly set the Java version in Gradle preferences.

[image]

Additional info: Eclipse itself starts up with an embedded Java 16 as per `SpringToolSuite4.ini`:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.200.v20210416-2027.jar
```

The Java version that Eclipse is started with, should not influence the Gradle Buildship plugin, but it does.

Comment: Could be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68322337/2834978)

Comment: @LMC good point, but in this case the project runs on Gradle 7.1