# vscode Cannot find a class with the main method(About gradle / springboot)

Tags: java, gradle

I'm collaborating with a friend on vscode, but my friend's spring works well, but mine doesn't work. There are two errors in total.

I tried various measures such as gradle plugin and java version, but it didn't work. For reference, the java version is 17.0.5 for both mac and vscode.
Thank you for watching.

```
Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.1-bin.zip'.
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'rezume_project'.
A problem occurred configuring root project 'rezume_project'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.4.
Required by:
    project : > org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:3.0.4
No matching variant of org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.4 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.6.1' but:
  - Variant 'apiElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.4 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
      - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
      - Other compatible attribute:
          - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.1')
  - Variant 'javadocElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.4 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
      - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
      - Other compatible attributes:
          - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
          - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
          - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.1')
  - Variant 'mavenOptionalApiElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin-maven-optional:3.0.4 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
      - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
      - Other compatible attribute:
          - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.1')
  - Variant 'mavenOptionalRuntimeElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin-maven-optional:3.0.4 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
      - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
      - Other compatible attribute:
          - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.1')
  - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.4 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
      - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
      - Other compatible attribute:
          - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.1')
  - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.4 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
      - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
      - Other compatible attributes:
          - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
          - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
          - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.1')
```

Comment: Hi & Welcome! sorry to correct, @"Leonard , but: spring-boot:3 works with java >= 8 ([proof](https://start.spring.io/)). Please show, @ddon, your (not-synced! ..so machine specific!)`settings.json`>`"java.configuration.runtimes"` ..also important: `"java.import.gradle.java.home"` [see also (not vs-code but  gradle) related)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68321708/592355),  [see also most relevant doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-build#_gradle) (you can [edit] your post;)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Reinstalling 'sdkman' solved the problem. thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

The line

> No matching variant of org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.4 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.6.1' but:

states that your project wants the library with Java 8 compatibility.
However,

> - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.4 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
>   - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8

says that all it could find, was a library that needs Java 17, which is correct as Spring Boot 3 requires Java 17.

So, your local build somehow runs on Java 8 or is configured with Java 8 as target. You should check that your shell runs with Java 17 or higher by running `java -version`.
The same applies to your IDE configuration.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Reinstalling 'sdkman' solved the problem. thank you for the reply!